# Virtual Terminals messed up with proprietary NVidia graphics driver

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, proprietary, mac-mini, virtual-terminal

At the current moment if I press ctrl + alt + F1 I get a blank screen for a few seconds then the bottom is filled with a mess of pixels (mainly white and a bit of brown). When I put in the open source drivers the virtual terminals work just fine, but I have no graphics acceleration :(. Any way to fix the terminals with the proprietary driver?

Answer (score 1):

In your Grub2 options, [remove `vga=somenumber` and add `xforcevesa`](http://www.vsubhash.com/article.asp?id=13&info=Ubuntu_and_Gnome_Diary#blank_tty_with_nvidia_proprietary_driver). In 10.10, there is a different option - `nomodeset`.

Comment: Where would I find my Grub2 options? (Sorry I'm still getting used to Ubuntu and Linux in general)

Comment: To do this, when the computer boots and the Grub menu is displayed, press the "E" key to edit the boot parameters. In the linux line, remove vga=somenumber and put xforcevesa. Then, press Ctrl+X to boot with new parameters. I suggest you first read this Grub 2 tutorial - http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html